# change line to bold, if it ends with a colon, and only contains one word

Tags: php, regex

How do I change the word to bold, if there is only one word on a line with a colon at the end?

data comes from at text field in mysql database, and code is php

Comment: Some code to show us ?

Comment: What does means "with a colon at the end" ?

Comment: Please provide some code. I would say you need to check for the colon (maybe regex). You will then need to wrap it a `<b>` tag or add some css properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the word and substitute surrounded by `<b>`

```
^(\w+):$
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/hK2hJ4/5)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/^(\\w+):$/m";
$str = "abc:\nabc\nabc:xyz\n";
$subst = '<b>$1</b>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)

  )                        end of \1
  :                        ':'
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Note: **there is only one word on a line with a colon at the end**

Comment: Look at the demo. `\w` matches just one word. I used `:$` to check for end of line with colon.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~^\w+:$~', '<b>$0</b>', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `\w+` matches one or more word chars
- `:` matches the colon
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string
- We replace with `<b>`, the overall match (referenced by `$0`) and `</b>`